# Oceanic-atmospheric coupling between the Indian Ocean and the Pacific Ocean basins

Tags: oceanography, enso, climatology, ocean-models

The two great basins - Indian Ocean and Pacific Ocean have their respective oscillations: Indian Ocean Dipole and El Nino Southern oscillation that affect the climate of the regions as well as the world at large. Is there any scientific agreement that the two basins are coupled at the oceanic level and the atmospheric level ? What are the observable manifestations of this coupling between basins?

Comment: [Investigation of coupled ocean-atmospheric biennial mechanisms in the tropical Indian and Pacific regions](https://www.proquest.com/openview/7dcd8fee53ffe3ce9bd0df8a18b801f6/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y) may be helpful.

Comment: This discusses the influence of IOD on ENSO (observations + model results) and also lists a few references that further discuss their interaction (references 27-31): [A model for super El Niños](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6023905/pdf/41467_2018_Article_4803.pdf)

Comment: @J.Fregin You can write it up and I can upvote. It's a really old question and I had forgotten I had asked it. Six years is a long time..

Comment: @PadmanabhaChowdhury Please go ahead and answer it and I can upvote

Comment: I don't feel confident answering to be honest. It is a really interesting question though.

Comment: @J.Fregin These questions were asked when the group was new and we(original users) had to ask questions daily to increase the questions per day. Nowadays there is no such problem.

Comment: This topic is very new to me but it's very interesting. I need to study more on this. If I get proper explanation, I will try to answer.